# Average time from as.POSIXct ignoring dates using circular statistics

Tags: r, tidyverse, posixct, psych

I am looking to create a simple custom function I can integrate into a dplyr pipe workflow.

I want to calculate the mean of a time excluding dates. So for instance, given a sequence of POSIXct I want to extract the time and calculate average. However, one added complication is that time is circular, meaning that 00:00:00 and 23:00:00 are very close to each other in time terms, but arithmetically not so close. So I can't just use something like `mean(time_vector)` to calculate average.

I have seen the package psych which has a function called `circadian.mean` to calculate a circular average. However, it only takes decimal hours, so there's some juggling I have had to do before getting a valid output. For instance:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(psych)

df = data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2019-07-14 23:00:17",
                                        "2019-07-14 23:40:20",
                                        "2019-07-14 00:12:45",
                                        "2019-07-14 00:17:19"), tz = "UTC"))

decimal_hours_vector = df %>% 
  mutate(hours = hour(datetime)) %>% # extracting hours
  mutate(minutes = minute(datetime)) %>% # extracting minutes
  mutate(seconds = second(datetime)) %>% # extracting seconds
  mutate(dec_min = (minutes/60*100)/100) %>% # converting minutes to decimal hour
  mutate(dec_sec = (seconds/60/60*100)/100) %>% # converting seconds to decimal hour
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dec_hour = sum(hours,dec_min,dec_sec)) %>% # summing all three time columns rowwise
  ungroup() %>% # ungrouping
  pull(dec_hour) # extracting dec_hour as vector to use in circadian.mean
 
# calculating average time with psych 
average_time = circadian.mean(decimal_hours_vector)
```

So, I think the above works but is very cumbersome. Also, I still haven't worked out whether it makes sense to convert the final output back in hh:mm:ss or whether it should stay in the decimal format, and whether everything is working as it should.

As opposed to using the laborious process above, is there a better or more sensible way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to calculate modulo remainders of the decimal time after division by 12 or 24 hours, but I cannot tell what rule you actually want. Specify some more examples. POSIXct objects are actually already decimal numbers underneath their class attributes. I'm thinking you need to say what the right answer is for a larger set of examples.

Comment: mmm.....I am very confused to be honest. I can give a general example, perhaps that would help? Let's say I'm interested in the average time of entry to a shop, people are going in from 9 am to 5 pm at all times. I ultimately want a tractable time which I can say is my peak time of flow. This is ignoring days, just interested in hours, min secs.

Comment: If you are restricting the domain to a span of less then 8 hours I don't think you need to tie yourself up in knots.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps that was a stupid example. Actual dataset has times across the span of 8 months across 24 hours.

Comment: Then you need to say what the right answer really is. Your consultants cannot say what that is. If there were 24 times were equally spaced over 24 hours what would the "mean" be? 12 noon? You might want to study "circular statistics". There is a package named,   ... wait for it ... "circular".

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. I didn't think it would be so complicated but I've opened a can of worms it seems.

Comment: It might help to step back to consider the real-world situation (not described) and define the goals of having a single summary value. Maybe you want a circular distribution rather than a mean.